# Infinite while-loop as well as problems reading to file

Tags: java, arrays, file, count

Explanation of program:

> I have this program of mine which is intended to read every word from
>   a file (large one) and then check if the words already exist in a
>   word-array which keeps the unique words or not. If not, add the word
>   to the end of the array, and add +1 to a uniquewordcounter as well as
>   to a counting array at the same index.. If the word already is located
>   somewhere in the array, it should locate the index-number, and on the
>   same index-number in a counting-array increase the value with 1. This
>   it should do while the file has more content. I am not allowed to use HashMaps either.

My program does, however, go into an infinite while-loop when it is going to read the file, and the count of uniquewords is easily above 100.000 in a blink of an eye, but it should maximum be 5000...

Here is the code:

```
class Oblig3A{
    public static void main(String[]args){

    OrdAnalyse oa = new OrdAnalyse();
    String filArgs=args[0];
    oa.analyseMetode(filArgs);
    }
}

class OrdAnalyse{
    void analyseMetode(String filArgs){

    //Begins with naming all of the needed variables
    Scanner input, innfil;
    String[] ord, fortelling;
    int[] antall;
    int antUnikeOrd, totalSum;
    PrintWriter utfil;

    //Declaring most of them.
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ord=new String[5000];
    antall=new int[5000];
    antUnikeOrd=0;
    totalSum=0;
    try{
        innfil=new Scanner(new File(filArgs));



    //The problem is located here somewhere:
        while(innfil.hasNext()){
        fortelling=innfil.nextLine().toLowerCase().split(" ");

        ord[0]=innfil.next().toLowerCase();

            for(int i=0; i<fortelling.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<5000; j++){
            if(fortelling[i].equals(ord[j])){
                antall[j]+=1;
                System.out.print("heo");
            }else{
                ord[j]=fortelling[i];
                antall[j]+=1;
                antUnikeOrd+=1;
                }
            System.out.println(ord.length);
            System.out.println(antUnikeOrd);

            }
        }
        }
        innfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   // Here the program will write all the info acquired above into a file called Oppsummering.txt, which it will make.
    try{
        utfil=new PrintWriter(new File("Oppsummering.txt"));

        for(int i=0; i<antall.length; i++){
        totalSum+=antall[i];
        }

        utfil.println("Antall ord lest: " +totalSum+ " og antall unike ord: "+antUnikeOrd);

        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){

        utfil.println(ord[i]+("  ")+antall[i]);
        }
        utfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is a prime example why even for your private projects you should code everything in English. ;)

Comment: Ouch, I probably should :P I'll edit the comments

Answer (score 2):

```
/The problem is located here somewhere:
    Scanner keepTrack=infill.next();
    while(keepTrack.next().Equals(null)){
    fortelling=innfil.nextLine().toLowerCase().split(" ");

    ord[0]=innfil.next().toLowerCase();

        for(int i=0; i<fortelling.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<5000; j++){
        if(fortelling[i].equals(ord[j])){
            antall[j]+=1;
            System.out.print("heo");
        }else{
            ord[j]=fortelling[i];
            antall[j]+=1;
            antUnikeOrd+=1;
            }
        System.out.println(ord.length);
        System.out.println(antUnikeOrd);

        }
    }
    infill=infill.next();
    keepTrack=infill;
    }
    innfil.close();
}
```

Try this i am not sure if its working or no!

I think that the problem is that you are looping only on one element not to all of them.

Good luck!!!

Comment: There are no HashMap in the code. This is your while loop with some modifications.

Comment: Sorry, commented to wrong answer... Slept 4 hours tonight because of this one :P 
Anyways: I cannot get the line: Scanner Keeptrack=innfil.hasNext(); to work? Tried a few things, but either it cannot find an appropriate operator, or it tells me that it won't accept it because it wants string, but get boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have direct answer for your question but I have working and much simplier solution for you.
I must admit that I am lazy and analyzing your code is to much for a person like me :)partially because it is not in english and partially because the code could be much simpler if you had used correct containers. I have tested your code with smaller files and it loops forever also so the size does not matter.

As I said it can be done much simplier if proper container has been used. 
So here is my solution:

```
    Map<String, Integer> wordsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp\\input.txt"));
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next();
        wordsMap.put(word ,wordsMap.containsKey( word ) ? wordsMap.get( word ) + 1 : 1);
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of unique words: "+wordsMap.size());
    for( String word : wordsMap.keySet()){
        System.out.println("Word \""+word+"\" occurs "+wordsMap.get(word)+" times.");
    }
```

The counting logic is in while loop. Printing occurs in for loop you can change system output with file and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks for the input! I appreciate it. And I am really sorry, I forgot to mention: We are not allowed to use hashmaps... -.-

Comment: Ok I see. Another thing that came to my head is that having lines like:
fortelling=innfil.nextLine().toLowerCase().split(" ");
ord[0]=innfil.next().toLowerCase();
is dangerous because for the second time you don't check if there is something to get. So you are relying on the format of input file which implies you should have even number of lines and the last line should be a single word. Otherwise you can get weird behaviour depending what is in your file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different issues here that are stopping your program from working as expected. Firstly, your use of the scanner is not giving you the results you might expect. Assume that we have a very simple input file, as follows:

```
apple banana carrot
alligator baboon crocodile
```

To begin with, the scanner is positioned at the start of the file, like so:

```
|apple banana carrot
alligator baboon crocodile
```

When you call `.nextLine()` the scanner advances its cursor past the end of the line and returns all of the data that it passed over. So `fortelling` becomes set to `["apple", "banana", "carrot"]` and the scanner is positioned at the start of the second line, like so:

```
apple banana carrot
|alligator baboon crocodile
```

So when you call `.next()`, `ord[0]` becomes set to "alligator" and the cursor is moved again. Scanners are not rewindable, so if you have read some data once using one of the next... methods, you cannot read it again with the same scanner.

Your second problem is the logic inside your loops. `fortelling[i].equals(ord[j])` will always evaluate to false, because none of the strings in `fortelling` are "alligator". Therefore the following lines are always executed:

```
ord[j]=fortelling[i];
antall[j]+=1;
antUnikeOrd+=1;
```

Because of your inner loop, these lines will be repeated 5000 times for every word in the first line of the file. So after the first iteration of the outer loop, the variables will look like this:

```
ord : [ "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", ... ]
antall : [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... ]
antUnikeOrd : 5000
```

After the second it will be:

```
ord : [ "banana", "banana", "banana", "banana", "banana", ... ]
antall : [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ... ]
antUnikeOrd : 10000
```

Then:

```
ord : [ "carrot", "carrot", "carrot", "carrot", "carrot", ... ]
antall : [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ... ]
antUnikeOrd : 15000
```

This is why you count of unique words increases so quickly. 5000 is added to it for every word you process. Even if the scanner problem was not present, the logic here is not correct. If a word matches an existing one, you only want to take action once, not 5000 times. A well-placed `break` statement would probably fix this.

Also, you are changing the value of `ord[0]` with every iteration of the while loop. If this array is supposed to be a list of unique words, this cannot be correct. Each item in `ord` should be set once and only once.

I didn't mean for this to become a large code-review, but there you go. I hope you find it useful!